# I can tell you/ I'm telling you/ I tell you

Tags: phrase-usage, idiomatic-language

Are 'I can tell you/ I'm telling you/ I tell you' interchangeable and used to emphasize that you're telling the truth? For example:

1. I can tell you that he's lying.
2. I'm telling you, he's really good at this game.
3. You'll lose against him. I tell you.

Comment: All of your 3 sentences have no connection with each other in their meanings. And how could you have an idea that the all 3 you are talking are "interchangeable"??

Answer (score 4):

In short, I can tell you, **yes, they are**. The meanings are similar, as follows:

1. **I *can* tell you that yada yada** declares that I *have in my power* to make a statement ("yada yada"), implying that I *know the facts of the matter*. It is not a speech act: I do not actually tell you, I only explain that I'm able to. However, in practice it is used to *make* the statement.
2. **I'm *telling* you, yada, yada** declares that I *am presently acting to make a statement*. Again, I am *authenticating* the statement ("yada, yada"); I suppose that you will trust my criteria. It says that I *am declaring*, but again is used to *make* the statement.
3. **Yada, yada. I *tell* you.** In this case, the declaration ("Yada, yada") is already made, and emphasis is given by informing you that I *act right now to make the statement*. It uses a different verb conjugation than (2). Again, I am authenticating a fact based on your trust of my judgement.

In all of them, the statement is made or implied, and I hope that in considering the fact that I am telling you will make you review the statement in this context, and in thinking about it again it will "rivet" the facts in your mind.
The emphasis is weakened a bit by self-reference; if "I tell you" is the only argument that I can give, I hope you will have the discernment to take it with a grain of salt. So, to back my argument up, here is what [Cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/i-m-telling-you) has to say:

> (also I tell you, I can tell you) used to emphasize that what you are saying is true, and should be believed: *I'm telling you, he's the best player in the American League. We've been waiting a long time for this, I'll tell you.*

Also see [I'll tell you what](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28I%2FI%27ll%29%20tell%20you%20what) at Mirriam-Webster.

Comment: I associate the phrase "I tell you!" with Humphrey Bogart in some movie or other from the 1940s.